# Searching dict within a list

Tags: python, list, set

If I have the following list of items for a shopping store:

```
shop_list = [{'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}, 
             {'item': 'banana', 'amount': 12, 'cost': 6}, 
             {'item': 'strawberry', 'amount': 8, 'cost': 9}]
```

So I have several dicts within a list. I want to find out how to get the item dict knowing the item. For example:

```
def x(item)
    #do something to get the dict
    print dict
x('apple')          #print {'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}
x('banana')          #print {'item': 'banana', 'amount': 12, 'cost': 6}
```

What's the shortest, most efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you are down-voting, please leave a helpful comment. Don't be lazy. Let's be more welcoming to newer members. A mistake/typo doesn't make a question down-vote worthy.

Comment: Can there be more than one "dicts" with the same "item"?

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to lookup entries by their `'item'`, then you should consider having a `dict` which keys are the `'item'` instead of a `list` of `dict`.

```
shop_list = {
    'apple': {'amount': 10, 'cost': 5},
    'banana': {'amount': 12, 'cost': 6},
    'strawberry': {'amount': 8, 'cost': 9}
}

shop_list['banana'] # {'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}
```

In particular, this makes the lookup *O(1)* instead of the *O(n)* required for traversing the `list`.

If you cannot update the code that generated the original `shop_list`, then you can transform the already existing data with a dict-comprehension.

```
formatted_shop_list = {product['item']: product for product in shop_list}
```

Comment: This is a very sound advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
def x(shop_list, item): # remove first parameter if you want to use global variable
    for i in shop_list:
        if i['item'] == item:
            return i
```

Then, you can call this function as:

```
>>> todays_shop_list = [{'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}, 
...                     {'item': 'banana', 'amount': 12, 'cost': 6}, 
...                     {'item': 'strawberry', 'amount': 8, 'cost': 9}]

>>> x(todays_shop_list, 'apple')
{'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through the list and just extract the dict that matches your shop item:

```
def shop_item(shop_list, item):
    return next((x for x in shop_list if x['item'] == item), None)
    # or next(filter(lambda x: x['item'] == item, shop_list), None)
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> shop_list = [{'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5},
...              {'item': 'banana', 'amount': 12, 'cost': 6},
...              {'item': 'strawberry', 'amount': 8, 'cost': 9}]
>>> shop_item(shop_list, 'apple')
{'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}
>>> shop_item(shop_list, 'grape')
None
```

The above uses [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression to iterate though the list until the condition is met, and returns `None` if item is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def x(item):
    return [elements for elements in shop_list if elements['item'] == item]

x('apple')          #print {'item': 'apple', 'amount': 10, 'cost': 5}
x('banana')          #print {'item': 'banana', 'amount': 12, 'cost': 6}
```

This will return the list item if found

```
[{'amount': 12, 'cost': 6, 'item': 'banana'}]
```

and if the result is not found an `empty list` will be returned.